# Angular2: Location two steps back

Tags: angular, typescript

Is there way to on `(click) goBack($event)` i need to go back two steps instead just this.location.back() is there list of location array and i need to cut one last element.

Comment: Is there _no way_ that the user can land on this route directly from anything except following links, like a bookmark, or clicking a link in an email or something? If so, this is a very fragile way to navigate.

Comment: i see, thank you. i will consider it.

Comment: I decide to listen advise and use static links for some workflow. Thank you. You can make answer so i can check.

Comment: Done, and a further +1 for changing your approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there is *absolutely no way* that the user can land on this route directly (such as following links, storing a bookmark, or clicking a link in an email, etc) it will be too fragile.

What if someone bookmarked the page but the "home" link actually fires `location.back()`: they'll end up on whatever site they were on before.

You should use static linking to known routes instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [window.history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history)

```
window.history.go(-2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is back two levels, you should be able to do something like:

```
this.router.navigate(['../../'], { relativeTo: this.route });
```

Comment: TIL! But can you please clarify if this will go "back" or "up"? For example, if I navigated from `/home` => `/contact/us/survey` => `/contact/us/survey/2018`, will I end up at `/home` or `/contact/us`? I think OP wants the former.

Comment: This should go to `/contact/us`